# Win2k8: How to set a 'Deny File Name Extension' rule in IIS?

Tags: iis, powershell

Does anyone know how to use Powershell to create a 'Deny File Name Extension' rule, so that certain files will not be served by IIS?

For example, I want to set a rule to deny all .txt files from being served up with IIS.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(
"Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, 
Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35") > $null

$serverManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager

# Default Web Site
$siteId = 1
$site = $serverManager.Sites | where { $_.Id -eq $siteID }   

#
# Sets the filter in the site's web.config
#
$config = $site.GetWebConfiguration()
$requestFilteringSection = `
      $config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering")

#
# Or delete last two lines and use next two instead to set in applicationHost.config
#
# $config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
# $requestFilteringSection = `
    $config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/requestFiltering", $site.Name);

$fileExtensionsElement = `
      $requestFilteringSection.GetChildElement("fileExtensions")
$fileExtensionsCollection = $fileExtensionsElement.GetCollection()
$addElement = $fileExtensionsCollection.CreateElement("add")
$addElement["fileExtension"] = ".txt"
$addElement["allowed"] = $false
$fileExtensionsCollection.Add($addElement)

$serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

You could also use `appcmd.exe`:

Configure in site `web.config`:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /+"fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.txt',allowed='False']"
```

Or configure in `applicationHost.config`:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /+"fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.bong',allowed='False']" /commit:apphost
```